# Empty Jboss files post removal of old application bulid file

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

I have a very strange situation.
My application build file was deployed in jboss and i accidentally installed the new build file without removing old build file.
Now when both the build files were present ,i removed the old build file forcefully and without stopping the jboss process.Which has resulted in following empty files with 0kb

cache-invalidation-service.xml, sqlexception-service.xml, jbossjca-service.xml. jboss-local-jdbc.rar, jboss-mx-ext.sar under server/tomcat-clustered/deploy/

i need to know,what could have triggered that has caused only these files to go empty.

Thanks..

Comment: I'd recommend you post this question over in [jboss developer forums](https://developer.jboss.org/welcome) as it is strange as just removing your build file shouldnt cause that - but it's actually a little unclear as to what you mean by a build file as a ant or maven build file does not get deployed to the jboss deployments folder your EAR, WAR or EJB JAR gets deployed.  If you didnt make any modifications to the empty files you listed above, just download another copy of JBoss and replace the empty files with the ones included in the download.  You can remove or add an app while jboss runs.